# Рисование на SurfaceView не обновляется

Tags: android, glsurfaceview

Здравствуйте, есть класс, унаследованный от `SurfaceView`

```
public class Pointer extends SurfaceView
{
float fromX, fromY, toX, toY;
public Pointer(Context c){
    super(c);
}

public Pointer(Context c, AttributeSet attrs){
    super(c, attrs);
}
public void set(float fromX, float fromY, float toX, float toY){
    this.fromX = fromX;
    this.fromY = fromY;
    this.toX = toX;
    this.toY = toY;
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas)
{
    Paint p = new Paint();
    p.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    p.setStrokeWidth(6);
    canvas.drawLine(fromX, fromY, toX, toY, p);
}
}
```

И его тэг в разметке. Нахожу его по `id`

```
Pointer ball = (Pointer) findViewById(R.id.pointer)
ball.setZOrderOnTop(true)
```

Вот метод для обновления переменных

```
public void getCenter(float x, float y){
    //координаты левой сетки
    float leftTableX = game_table1.getX();
    float leftTableY = game_table1.getY();
    //координаты правой сетки
    float rightTableX = game_table2.getX();
    float rightTableY = game_table2.getY();
    //отступы от экрана левой сетки
    float leftFullX = leftGridBox.getX();
    float leftFullY = leftGridBox.getY();
    //отступы от экрана правой сетки
    float rightFullX = rightGridBox.getX();
    float rightFullY = rightGridBox.getY();
    //отступы между сеткой и границей
    float insideBoxX = insideLeftBox.getX();
    float insideBoxY = insideLeftBox.getY();
    //координаты центра левой сетки
    ball.invalidate();
    rightCenterX = rightFullX + insideBoxX + rightTableX + game_table1.getWidth() / 2;
    rightCenterY = rightFullY + insideBoxY + rightTableY + game_table1.getWidth() / 2;
    //координаты выбранной ячейки
    clickX = leftFullX + insideBoxX + leftTableX + x;
    clickY = leftFullY + insideBoxY + leftTableY + y;
    ball.invalidate();
    ball.set(rightCenterX, rightCenterY, clickX, clickY);
}
```

Метод вызывается по клику на сетке, но это не важно. Главное, что данные меняются, отправляются в сеттер, но линия не перерисовывается. На названия методов, классов и переменных прошу не обращать внимания, логика часто менялась.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Используйте метод `invalidate()` у `SurfaceView` при изменении параметров

**UPD:**

Прошу прощения, решение, которое я предложил - неверно, оно подходит для кастомных компонентов. Как вариант могу предложить Вам создать свой view-компонент унаследованный от `SurfaceView`, перегрузить у него метод `onDraw` так, чтобы внутри этого метода рисовались линии. И тогда уже при изменении значений переменных вызывайте `invalidate()`

Comment: Вызываю `ball.invalidate()` после изменения переменах, лини нет. Кстати, а этот способ подойдёт для отрисовки движения?

Comment: **upd** класс есть, а что мне в разметке писать?

Comment: Создал класс и метод обновляющий в нем данные. При смене данных отправляю их в метод и все равно ничего не происходит

Comment: Можно увидеть реализацию?

Comment: Обновил вопрос.

Comment: @СергейГрушин Разбираюсь в вопросе вместе с Вами и наткнулся на довольно полезную статью https://habrahabr.ru/post/126316/

Comment: Уж слишком она старая, не верю, что так много кода надо.

Comment: @СергейГрушин во всех примерах я видел необходимость использования своего потока для рисования. Вот ещё 1 пример http://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/311-urok-141-risovanie-dostup-k-canvas.html